# composer: Where should I install it?

Tags: composer-php

I have installed composer in a private directory ".composer" and I am calling the composer autoloader from my public PHP script by referencing it fully:
**include_once '/home/my_account/.composer/vendor/autoload';**

However, when I initialise one of the installed dependencies (PHPDebugBar) I notice that it is trying to locate all its files locally: ie **/vendor/DebugBar** rather than **/home/my_account/.composer/vendor/DebugBar**

Should I have installed composer in my public folder? I have a few subdomains, so do I need to install composer in each subdomain? Surely not.

How can I inform PHPDebugBar that the files are in a specified root folder.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can generally install composer wherever you want and .composer in the root is fine.

However, in the case of PHP DebugBar specifically it needs to be in the same root directory as the public web files because DebugBar is heavily dependent on JavaScript files which it is calling client side. Client side file cannot access to root. This makes DebugBar a poor candidate for composer.

That said, I found DebugBar to be annoying so I deleted it.